# Overlapping Lists, CSS isn't pushing it down

Tags: css

I've added padding and margin to the li's themselves, but it spaces them out too far.  I'm trying to figure why the longer chapters won't just push the bottom li down a line and keep on going.

[Here is the test page.](http://dermsurgscientific.com/site/wai/index.html)

This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="sidebar">
            <h2> <a href="#">Contents</a> </h2>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3><a href="#">Part 1: Food  the Skin</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <ul id="partOne" class="toc">
                        <li><h3>01:</h3><a href="#">The Use of Fire</a></li>
                        <li><h3>02:</h3><a href="#">Downsides to Using Heat</a></li>
                        <li><h3>03:</h3><a href="#">Altered Protein</a></li>
                        <li><h3>04:</h3><a href="#">Protein Digestion</a></li>
                        <li><h3>05:</h3><a href="#">Protein in the Skin</a></li>
                        <li><h3>06:</h3><a href="#">Decomposition of Redundant Protein</a></li>
                        <li><h3>07:</h3><a href="#">Protein & Water</a></li>
                        <li><h3>08:</h3><a href="#">Swollen Skin,Cellulite & Treatments</a></li>
                        <li><h3>09:</h3><a href="#">Dry Skin</a></li>
                        <li><h3>10:</h3><a href="#">How to Rid </a></li>
                        <br/>
                        <li><h3>11:</h3><a href="#">Cellulite</a></li>
                        <li><h3>12:</h3><a href="#">Visibility of Fat Cells </a></li>
                        <li><h3>13:</h3><a href="#">Cellulite & Skin Tone</a></li>
                        <li><h3>14:</h3><a href="#">Cellulite & Treatments</a></li>
                        <br/>
                        <li><h3>15:</h3><a href="#">Acne: In Short</a></li>
                        <li><h3>16:</h3><a href="#">Acne & Hygiene</a></li>
                        <li><h3>17:</h3><a href="#">Acne & Hormones</a></li>
                        <li><h3>18:</h3><a href="#">Acne & Peeling </a></li>
                        <li><h3>19:</h3><a href="#">How to Eliminate Acne, Cellulite & Treatments</a></li>
                        <li><h3>20:</h3><a href="#">What Type of Acne</a></li>
                        <li><h3>21:</h3><a href="#">Susceptibility to Acne</a></li>
                        <li><h3>22:</h3><a href="#">Menstruation & Acne</a></li>
                        <li><h3>23:</h3><a href="#">Acne & Diet-results, Cellulite & Treatments</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Part 2: Nutrients & Toxins</a></h3>
                <div>Second content</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Part 3: The Diet</a></h3>
                <div>Second content</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Part 4: Losing Weight Naturally & Lastingly</a></h3>
                <div>Second content</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
        #accordion{
        margin: 10px;
    }
        #accordion h3{
            font-size:16px;
        }
        #accordion h3 a{

        }
        #accordion h3 a:hover{

        }
        .toc{
            list-style:none;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
            .toc li{
                width: 220px;
                height:18px;
            }
            #accordion div > ul{
                padding: 10px 0 0 0;
            }
            #partOne h3{
                float:left;
                width: 25px;
                padding: 0 3px 0 0;
                font-weight:normal;
            }
            #partOne a{


                color: blue;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            #partOne a:hover{
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
```

Can't get this problem solved after a couple of hours!

Comment: `<br>`s don't belong in `<ul>`s.

Comment: Any reason why you're using headers inside the lists? The h3's look like they're causing issues

Comment: I'll try using something else inside the lists.  I didn't know that was a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the `height` property from the `.toc li` style declaration:**

```
.toc li {
    width: 220px;
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mTMD2/)

If you'd like to set the line height of the `li`s, use [**`line-height`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height) CSS property. Also, consider replacing `&` with `&amp;`, reference [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Comment: I'm aware of the w3schools link. Please suggest a better reference if possible.

Comment: Thanks paislee, just gotta that float lining things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sure what you're trying to do, but why not use an [ordered list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) instead so you don't need to manually type the parts?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because you are fixing the height of the LIs, if you remove the height you will also have to "contain" or "clear" the floated H3s. One way to do that is to set the LIs overflow property.

```
.toc li {
    width: 220px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

*(Also I'm pretty sure putting those BRs in the UL where you have is not valid HTML)*